# How to bounce animation when scroll?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this .png that I wanted to make it bounce a little every time it detects a scroll movement but I'm not good in javascript and css. I hope you guys can help me

```
<div class="arrownav bounce">
  <a href="" class="logo">
    <img src="{{ asset('assets/img/arrow down.png') }}" height="45">
  </a>
</div>
```

I am now using a css that made the image bounce
this is the code:

```
  .bounce {
    -webkit-animation:bounce 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation:bounce 1s infinite;
    -o-animation:bounce 1s infinite;
    animation:bounce 1s infinite;

  }

  @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%       { bottom:0px; }
    50%      { bottom:15px; }
    100%     {bottom:30;}
  }

   @-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0%       { bottom:0px; }
    50%      { bottom:15px; }
    100%     {bottom:30;}
  }

   @-o-keyframes bounce {
    0%       { bottom:0px; }
    50%      { bottom:15px; }
    100%     {bottom:30;}
  }

   @keyframes bounce {
    0%       { bottom:0px; }
    50%      { bottom:15px; }
    100%     {bottom:30;}
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is the missing unit in all `@keyframes`, right here:

```
100%     {bottom:30;}
```

This should be:

```
100%     { bottom:30px; }
```

---

You've used the `bottom` style in you animation, which is perfectly fine, but in order for it to work the element's `position` needs to be either `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` (more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/#article-header-id-0)).

```
.bounce {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: bounce 1s infinite;
    -o-animation: bounce 1s infinite;
    animation: bounce 1s infinite;
}
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcodxsuo/).

---

**Bonus**
Another way to change the element's position in the animation is the `transform` style, instead of using `bottom`. When you use `transform`, you don't need `position: relative;`.

```
@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLggrxL8/)

Comment: Thank you very much